# Is $\mathbb{R}^2$ the same as my dear $\mathbb{C}^2$?

Tags: vector-spaces

The question is$$\text{Is }\mathbb{R}^2\text{ a subspace of }\mathbb{C}^2?$$My first thing to think about it now is $$\text{Is }\mathbb{R}^2\text{ a subset of }\mathbb{C}^2?$$ I think no because what is $\mathbb{R}^2$ it's like all those pairs $(0,1)$ right? and what is $\mathbb{C}^2$ it's like euh $((a,b),(c,d))$ (because a complex number is a pair of two numbers with multiplication defined as $(a,b)(c,d)=(ac-bd,ad+bc)$ and addition $(a,b)+(c,d)=(a+c,b+d)$) so they aren't the same$$$$another point is of course $\mathbb{R}^2$ is a vector space over $\mathbb{R}$ with specific operations, and $\mathbb{C}^2$ is a vector space over $\mathbb{C}$ with different operations, so my gut feeling tells me that they can't be the same;;;;;;;; in general if $V$ is  a vector space over $D$ with operations $+,\times$ and $U$ is a vector space over $B$ with operations $\oplus,\otimes$ and $B\ne D$ can it be the case that $U$ is a subset of $V$? Over what?

Comment: $\newcommand{\RR}{\mathbb{R}}
\newcommand{\CC}{\mathbb{C}}$ 
Well, if $\RR$ is a subset of $\CC$, then $\RR \times \RR$ can be seen as a subset of $\CC \times \CC$, as the pairs of points that only involve real numbers.

Comment: @PedroM. But the operations are different, also I don't think $\mathbb{R}$ is a subset of $\mathbb{C}$ since this very last one is a pair of two reals. and $\text{real number}\ne(\text{real number , 0})$

Comment: In Mathematics, we often identify things that are "pretty much equal'', even though they are technically not equal. In this particular case, the function $x \in \mathbb{R} \to (x,0) \in \mathbb{C}$ is continuous, respects sums and products etc: in short, working with (complex) $(x,0)$ is the same as working with (real) $x$, so we say that $\mathbb{R}$ is a subset of $\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: The title of the post is so bad...

Comment: @TroyWoo i'm so sorry my dear, can you change it?

Comment: @SQLInjection I think you should improve it yourself.

Comment: @TroyWoo i don't know, in general it's rather subjective, so if you don't like it you are the best one to improve it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Usually we say that $\mathbb R$ is a subset of $\mathbb C$, because any real number, such as $0$ or $2$ or $\pi$ is also a member of $\mathbb C$. There are [various schools of thought](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/876195/what-is-an-advatage-of-defining-mathbbc-as-a-set-containing-mathbbr) about how to justify this formally, but that doesn't need to concern us for the purpose of this question -- just so long as we accept that, say, $\pi\in\mathbb C$ is a true statement, which is definitely the case in ordinary everyday mathematics.

In this case it is indeed the case that $\mathbb R^2\subseteq \mathbb C^2$ because every element of the former is also in the latter.

For example $(\sqrt 2,\pi)\in \mathbb R^2$ is also in $\mathbb C^2$ because $(\sqrt2,\pi)=(\sqrt2+0i,\pi+0i)\in\mathbb C^2$.

So $\mathbb R^2$ is certainly a *subset* of $\mathbb C^2$. Whether it is also a *subspace* depends on which kind of vector space we consider $\mathbb C^2$. If we say $\mathbb C^2$ is a *complex* vector space, then $\mathbb R^2$ is not a subspace because it fails to be closed under scalar multiplication. But if $\mathbb C^2$ is a *real* vector space (with the obvious operations), then $\mathbb R^2$ *is* a subspace.

So the real answer is that the question is ambiguous.

Comment: Thanks, very instructive answer, clears up my misconception that $\text{real number}\ne(\text{real number , 0})$. What about my very last question?

Comment: @SQLInjection: In order to be subspaces the two vector spaces need to be over the same field. But if $(V,{+},{\times})$ and $(U,{\oplus},{\otimes})$ are vector spaces over the same field $F$, then we can say that $V$ is a subspace of $U$ if $V\subseteq U$ and $+$ equals the restriction of $\oplus$ to $V\times V$ and $\times$ equals the restriction of $\otimes$ to $F\times V$.

Comment: If $V$ is a vector space over $\mathbb C$, we can _derive_ a vector space over $\mathbb R$ from it, simply by restricting the multiplication operator to $\mathbb R\times V$. But we usually talk about the resulting space as a _different_ vector space, because the scalar field is different.

Comment: A right, understood perfectly now! many thanks my friend!

Comment: @HenningMakholm: Regarding your comment, I agree with your choice to have two different sums for $U$ and $V$, but there is no need for two cartesian products, as this refers simply to the standard set-theoretical notion.

Comment: @PedroM: Note that the $\times$ and $\otimes$ in the above comments are meant to be the _scalar_ products of the relevant vector spaces, not cartesian products. (This is not really standard notation, but it's what the OP used at the end of the question, and I didn't want to confuse the OP further by quibbling over his notation).

Comment: @HenningMakholm: Got it, I didn't see that.

Comment: @Henning: I think you are missing the point here. A real number, as usually defined, is _not_ a complex number, as usually defined. You are so used to the natural embedding $x \mapsto x+0i$ that you are forgetting that it is not an identity.

Comment: @TonyK: It can be an identity if you want to (see the "various schools of thought" link), and it _definitely is_ an identity the way mathematics is usually spoken of.

Comment: I totally disagree with your _definitely_. Perhaps it's how we were raised, but if somebody says "$\mathbb R$" to me, I think of Dedekind cuts, or equivalence classes of Cauchy sequences. I _definitely_ don't think of $\mathbb C$, unless it becomes relevant later on. Then I perform the embedding. By the way, does your identity extend to the quaternions too?

Comment: @TonyK: Nobody says you should think of complex number when someone says $\mathbb R$, but when someones says $\mathbb C$, you're certainly supposed to think of something that has $\mathbb R$ as a subset. You can define quaternions to be an actual superset of $\mathbb C$ if you want to, sure.

Answer (score 0):

According to most of the usual definitions, $\mathbb R$ is not a subset of $\mathbb C$. You are absolutely correct about this. In the same way, $\mathbb N$ is not a subset of $\mathbb Z$, which is not a subset of $\mathbb Q$, which is not a subset of $\mathbb R$.

However, $\mathbb N$ has a *natural embedding* in $\mathbb Z$, which has a *natural embedding* in $\mathbb Q$, etc. For instance, the integer $n \in \mathbb Z$ is mapped by this natural embedding to (the equivalence class of) the rational $\dfrac{n}{1} \in \mathbb Q$. And the real number $x \in \mathbb R$ is mapped to the complex number $x+0i \in \mathbb C$.

Often $-$ in fact, almost always $-$ this natural embedding is left implicit. So when $\mathbb R^2$ is treated as if it were a subset of $\mathbb C^2$, this is to be understood as $\mathbb R'^2$ being a subset of $\mathbb C^2$, where $\mathbb R'$ is the image of the natural embedding $\mathbb R \to \mathbb C$.

Comment: I didn't know about natural embeddings thanks, but what about the last question?