# Construction of number systems

Tags: elementary-set-theory, number-systems

I would like to get a book on set theory that presents the construction of number systems so that one really has:
$\Bbb N$ contained in $\Bbb Z$, $\Bbb Z$ contained in $\Bbb Q$, $\Bbb Q$ contained in $\Bbb R$, $\Bbb R$ contained in $\Bbb C$.
(As usual, $\Bbb N$ denotes the set of natural numbers, $\Bbb Z$ the set of integers, $\Bbb Q$ the set of rational numbers, $\Bbb R$ the set of real numbers, $\Bbb C$ the set of complex numbers.)
It seems to me that such a construction is presented in Solomon Feferman's Number Systems - Foundations of Algebra and Analysis.
I ask for help.

Comment: Um, if you already has the title of a book that does it in the way you prefer, then **what is your question here**?

Comment: It seems to me that, rather than manipulating the definitions of number systems to get each to be literally a subset of the next, it would be more useful to prove a general theorem saying that, if $A$ is isomorphic to a substructure of $B$, then $A$ is literally a substructure of an isomorphic copy of $B$. Then apply that theorem iteratively to the number systems you listed. (Caution: The obvious "proof" of the theorem, namely to replace in $B$ each element of the copy of $A$ with the corresponding element of $A$, is not in general correct, but easy to repair.)

Comment: @Henning Makholm:  I'm not sure if the book I mentioned brings the building I want to see.

Comment: @Andreas Blass:  Many thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: FWIW, [this answer of mine](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/876195/what-is-an-advatage-of-defining-mathbbc-as-a-set-containing-mathbbr/876277#876277) shows a bit more of how @Andreas's suggestion would go -- though not explicitly _phrased as_ a general theorem.

Comment: @Henning Makholm:  Thank you very much!